# Angularjs with keycloak auth keeps adding the same params to url after refresh

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I am using  angularjs and keycloak on my portal to authenticate.  The problem might be something I configurated wrong with keycloak or something that I am missing with angular that I should do.

When I log in to the page for the first time I get something like

```
http://localhost/index.html?code=dQ_OdChtwNj794waGS4JGXDkKPkZd5iOJ51B2KTGr-I.3d7dc148-1fc5-4d36-9bbf-a642c8d2a283&state=a8ab64ee-4296-4048-89e8-777bbf1f39b7
```

After I reload I get something like this

```
http://localhost/index.html?code=dQ_OdChtwNj794waGS4JGXDkKPkZd5iOJ51B2KTGr-I.3d7dc148-1fc5-4d36-9bbf-a642c8d2a283&state=a8ab64ee-4296-4048-89e8-777bbf1f39b7&prompt=none&code=vh3A5izxDs5dV2IhXkb_wQUtiXqW6Kq8rAdPhIvnSF4.f127afb6-4980-4367-add7-0a951a5741cb&state=864c8ff8-a1d5-4963-8375-7ed11c124b90
```

As I keep refreshing the page when I am developing prompt, code and state start to pile up and I end up having.

This is my code 
https://github.com/jdc18/angular-product-app-keycloak/blob/master/angular-product-app2/src/main/webapp/js/app.js
I have changed the code from that a little bit but it is basically the same. 
I am using ui-router instead of ng-route now but I have the same problem.

Also I am not sure if it is ok but with ng-route or ui-router if I click on any of my links, like profile I get something like

```
http://localhost/index.html?code=dQ_OdChtwNj794waGS4JGXDkKPkZd5iOJ51B2KTGr-I.3d7dc148-1fc5-4d36-9bbf-a642c8d2a283&state=a8ab64ee-4296-4048-89e8-777bbf1f39b7#/profile
```

with #/profile or #mylink at the end, I am not sure if this is intended.

Should I try to use something like $location to change the params or maybe change something with keycloak.

Comment: I have similar problem. I've checked your code on git and I'm wandering if you are close to solving this?

Comment: I found a work around I enabled html5

Comment: FIY i've integrated it with some help of code from https://github.com/liveoak-io/liveoak project. Basically you have to init keycloak before angular, and then bootstrap angular on success and REMOVE ng-app="" attribute when bootstraping angular!

Comment: Yeah I know, like in the example in the keycloak github repo

Answer (score 2):

Try with (**responseMode: 'query'**):

```
keycloak.init(onLoad: 'login-required', responseMode: 'query').success(->
.....
)
```

Doing so puts the keycloak details into the query params instead of after the `#` symbol on the redirect url returning to your page.

Comment: The link is dead. Could you please repost it?

Comment: https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/content/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html#_properties

Comment: Link dead again... (or possibly gitbook website changes related)